# Best practice to immideately stop Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have context, which may be used to produce prognosis. Algorithm to make prognosis based on context isn't part of my question. But it is time-expensive, so I moved it out from main thread. In any time context may be changed. When this happens app should restart prognosis producing with new input. Prognosis related to old context will became invalid, so its calculation should be interupted.

For now I use code:

```
public class BackgroundTasksManager {

public static final BackgroundTasksManager shared = new BackgroundTasksManager();

private ExecutorService conceptResultsExecutor = null;

private BackgroundTasksManager() { }

public void startConceptResultsCalculation(ConceptResultsCalculationInput input,
                                           Consumer<ConceptResultsCalculationOutput> callback) {
    ThreadGroup callbackGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    if (conceptResultsExecutor != null)
        conceptResultsExecutor.shutdownNow();

    conceptResultsExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    conceptResultsExecutor.submit(() -> {
        ConceptResultsCalculationOutput output = ConceptResultsCombinator.possbileResults(input);
        Thread callbackThread = new Thread(callbackGroup, () -> callback.accept(output));
        callbackThread.start();
    });
}
```

So, when I need to start prognosis calculation, I shut down old Executor and create new one. This solution works, but is it valid, or hide some dangerous nuances?

Comment: There is one single standard mechanism in java platform to interrupt a Thread. This is the interruption flag. And the thread should check the flag on its own. Any long/blocking operation should check this flag. For example, if you have a long running loop, you should check interrupted()/isInterrupted() flag periodically. BTW, to interrupt blocking IO operation like socket.read(), the better way is to close() the socket in another thread to exit from read() immediately with an IOException.

Comment: 2. There is no need to use a synthetic volatile flag to stop a thread calculation, but it may be a sign the thread is going to be stopped by user, so, set the flag closing to true and check it in catch section of your run() method. If !closing, you have a problem, otherwise this is expected exception to exit from run(). 3. Don't forget that typically it's recommended to restore interrupted flag after the InterruptedException is caught http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=251

Comment: @AnatolyG Sometime interrupt() is called to wake up a thread that is sleeping or waiting for a interruptible lock without the intention of stopping it. In this case the check interrupted()/isInterrupted() cannot be enough. Another problem with interrupts is that they interrupt some function in the middle and instead it could be preferable, for example, to read a file to the end and then check a custom flag.

Comment: @Andrea Of course, I can imagine such exclusive design solution :), but from my perspective this doesn't seem to be a canonical inter-thread communication mechanism like Object wait()/notify(),Locks+Conditions,BlockingQueues etc. I'd like to see an example in std lib or any well known lib. As for " interrupt some function in the middle", this is cooperative mechanism (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html), which means if this is your function, you can do what is required before you restore the interrupt flag and exit, for example, you close your file descriptors.

Comment: But if GUI thread just asked our unzip function to stop, I'd prefer the function to stop asap and do not read and unzip the rest of my 10gigs file) If we'd like to use the function in ExecutorService, the service doesn't know about our own custom flag, but about the interrupted only.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a thread - you either `interrupt` it, via a direct call to `Thread::interrupt` or, in your case, call `shutDownNow`, which will implicitly call that. Or you could have a `volatile boolean stop` flag, that some other thread needs to set and your thread needs to check.

If your threads do not respond to interrupts, that `shutDownNow` will not do anything, besides blocking *future* tasks to be scheduled on it.

Comment: So, I should manually check and handle Thread.interrupted() inside my Runnable?

Comment: @ЛомовСергей you should catch that interrupted exception. [here is an article that is almost 20 years old](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056-Shutting-down-Threads-Cleanly.html)